# Is it possible with Node-webkit to disable maximize on osx yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: javascript, macos, node-webkit

I've set the resizable to false in the manifest file, it works fine on windows 7 (maximize button is disabled), however on OSX, maximize button is not disabled, and it's still possible to enlarge the window.

Is there a workaround for this? I tried searching for information about this issue, however the information is outdated by 3 years, and solutions no longer apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add min/max width & min/max height. Or remove maximize button

Comment: Remove maximize button? Is that even possible?

Comment: I think you are talking for fullscreen in this case. try to add "fullscreen": false in manifest file. And yes you can remove buttons and build you own. just put "frame": false

Comment: Ah, right, but that removes all the buttons, however for the project I'm working on, the window buttons must be visible. I'll try the fullscreen, and let you know if it works for me

Comment: Perfect setting the fullscreen to false did the trick! Thank you!